# how to hide duplicate record in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please help me,how to hide duplicate record in mysql?
i have 2 table:
tbl_transaksi and tbl_item

tbl_transaksi

```
tanggal      kode_item
2014-05-24   A1
2014-05-24   A2
2014-05-24   A1
2014-02-10   A4
```

tbl_item

```
kode_item nama_barang
A1        PULPEN
A2        BAJU
A3        LAPTOP
A4        DASI
A5        SEPATU
```

i try to join

```
select a.tanggal,b.nama_barang from tbl_transaksi a inner join tbl_item b on a.kode_item=b.kode_item order by a.tanggal asc;
```

result

```
tanggal      nama_barang
2014-02-10   DASI 
2014-05-24   PULPEN
2014-05-24   BAJU
2014-05-24   PULPEN
```

but, I want the result like this

```
tanggal      nama_barang
2014-02-10   DASI
2014-05-24   PULPEN  
BAJU
PULPEN
```

how show like that?

Comment: Do that in your program logic. SQL is not meant for such operations.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle for this?

Comment: please give me example to show data like the above.
sorry i cannot speak english very well

Comment: i try to using "distinct" but the result not show like i want

Comment: i try "GROUP BY" but record BAJU and PULPEN gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four rows as you asked for

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    (`id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT key,`tanggal` varchar(10), `nama_barang` varchar(6))
;

insert into temp (tanggal, nama_barang)
select a.tanggal,b.nama_barang 
from tbl_transaksi a 
inner join tbl_item b on a.kode_item=b.kode_item 
order by a.tanggal asc;



select case when t1.tanggal=t2.tanggal then '' else t1.tanggal end tanggal, t1.nama_barang


from temp t1 left join temp t2
on t1.id-1=t2.id

drop table temp;
```

[TEST](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15b2b7/7)

Comment: this query also use to postgresql too ?

Comment: @Trisna You can use this approach for sure. Just make sure how to create an autoincrement column in postgres, and verify sintax.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
   select a.tanggal,Group_concat(b.nama_barang ) nama_barang
   from tbl_transaksi a 
   inner join tbl_item b 
   on a.kode_item=b.kode_item 
   GROUP BY a.tanggal
   order by a.tanggal asc;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10e5d/4)